# registerLanguage isn't defined in project

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to build an older rascal project: https://github.com/visknut/LudoscopeLite
It throws a CallFailed when trying to call registerLanguage.

I can find some references to registerLanguage across the web as part of util:IDE - neither are part of the current documentation here (IDE seems to have been succeeded by IDEServices) : https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Library/util/IDEServices/

- What was registerLanguage succeeded by? What do I need to change to get it to build?
- Is it possible to see documentation for an older version of rascal?
- Is it possible to install the eclipse plugin for an older version of rascal?

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of registerLanguage which have been rather stable during their lifetimes.

- One is for Eclipse, and offered by the rascal-eclipse plugin, in the util::IDE module. You can find the documented code here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-eclipse/blob/main/rascal-eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/util/IDE.rsc
- The other is for VScode, or the LSP more precisely, and its module is util::LanguageServer. The code is here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-language-servers/blob/main/rascal-lsp/src/main/rascal/util/LanguageServer.rsc

Both projects are on the backlog for documentation publication on rascal-mpl.org but that will probably offer not much more than what is in those files. Of course the demo projects for Pico for both are insightful.

The VScode version is incompatible with the older eclipse version, because it has different parameters. The VScode version is made to boot a fresh rascal runtime, load the required modules and start the LSP callback services, while the eclipse version would register the callbacks directly from the current terminal runtime.

About util::IDEServices; this is new code which originated from the VScode port but was partially back-ported to all other contexts. In eclipse you can ignore it if you want, or write more portable code with it which will also work in VScode and the commandline.

Installing older versions of Rascal requires installing much older versions of eclipse. You have to move both of them past the Java11 breakline.

Documentation for the older versions can be found in the git repositories by checking out release tags and reading the source .rsc or .md or .concept markdown.

Drop us a line if you get stuck?